# A modular recurence equation

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

Let $a$, $N$ are two positive odd integers with $a<N$. Define a squence $(a_i)_i$ as follows:

> $a_o = a$ and $a_i = 2 a_{i-1}(\text{mod }N)$ for $i\geq 1$.

Show that there exists a $T > 0$ such that $a_T = \frac{a+N}{2}$. In other words the folloing code snippet always terminate

```
def main(a,N):
print 'a={0} N={1}'.format(a,N)
term = (a+N)/2
while a != term:
    a = (2*a) % N
    print a
```

The first thing I notice that $a_i = 2^i a(\text{mod }N)$. Now suppose $a = 2^k a^{(k)} + 2^{k-1}a^{(k-1)} + \cdots + 2a^{(1)} + a^{(0)}$ in binary with $a^{(0)} = 1$(since $a$ is odd). So $2^ia = 2^{k+i} a^{(k)} + 2^{k+i-1}a^{(k-1)} + \cdots + 2^{i+1}a^{(1)} + 2^ia^{(0)}$ i.e., $a$ shifted to left by $i$ places(in binary). I am not sure what to do next.

The above code does terminate for all allowed values of $(a,N)$ in first 2000 integers.

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Your sequence is only defined $\pmod N$, so what does it mean to say $a_T=\frac {a+N}2$?

Comment: @lulu since $a<N$, $\frac{a+N}{2}<N$.

Comment: But, again, $a_n$ is only defined $\pmod N$.  So, do you just mean to write $a_T\equiv a\times 2^{-1}\pmod N$?  But that's obvious.

Comment: @lulu, do you mean to say $\frac{a+N}{2} = a/2(\pmod N)$? Suppose $a=13$ and $N = 21$. So the above sequence must hit the value 17.

Comment: I prefer to write $2^{-1}\pmod N$., though others do write $\frac 12$.  Anyway, we have $a_n\equiv 2^{n-1}a\pmod N$.  Letting $g$ be the order of $2\pmod N$, then $a_{g+1}\equiv a\pmod N$ and $a_{g}\equiv a\times 2^{-1}\pmod N$.

Comment: In your particular example, $g=6$ (since $2$ has order $6$ $\pmod {21}$, and we remark that $a_6\equiv 17\pmod {21}$ as you desire.

Comment: Should say:  my method finds the *least* $T$ that works, but you did not ask for that, though the algorithm does prove existence.  If you want an easier construction for a $T$ that works (but which may not be minimal), just use $\varphi(N)$.  For $N=21$, we have $\varphi(21)=12$ and, indeed, $a_{12}\equiv 17 \pmod {21}$